# How to point a subdomain to a subfolder

Tags: laravel, apache, mod-rewrite, ispconfig, ispconfig-3

I have an Apache server running ISPConfig. On a domain `example.com` I am pointing its subdomains to subfolders, e.g. `foo.example.com` to `/sub/foo`. **This works fine**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/example\.com/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /sub/%1/$1 [L]
```

Now I need to point one specific subdomain into a subfolder's subfolder (`bar.example.com` into `/sub/bar/public` to use Laravel). But for some reason, **this does not work**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bar\.example\.com/
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /sub/bar/public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/example\.com/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /sub/%1/$1 [L]
```

Comment: why not use virtual host?

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur I could do that but I'm trying to do it using ISPconfig without any "hacking" on the side. I know adding a vhost is not hacking of Apache but it is going around ISPconfig. The code above is put in a "Apache directives" field in the ISPconfig administration of this domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the `/` at the end of the domain name. If I delete it or put there `$`, it works.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bar\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /sub/bar/public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/example\.com/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /sub/%1/$1 [L]
```